# autopopulate field using user profile webservice in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, form

i have created infopath 2013 form for approval workflow in which i add initiator field which is filled using user profile service. its working but it has one error that every time different user login initiator name is changed a/c  to profile. i want it to unique. on first view load initiator value and it should be fixed in other views too. i dont understand where should i set this initiator value. [image]

Comment: To understand this issue better, could you please provide some screenshots about the issue that you met?

Comment: Kally_MSFT i have added screenshot below kindly look into it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screen short of this issue. i want to add profile name of that person who created the item but as you see initiator field pick value of every user who login to see the item.
[image]

Comment: Did you use "userName()" to show the values or other User profile web services? "userName()" function will return the user who is filling the form instead of the creator. could you provide a screenshot about the detail information about "Set a field's value" that you use to set Initiator's value in your first pic? In addition, you can try to use CreatedBy field to show the creator.